# Which functions have all the common $\forall\exists$-properties of continuous functions?

Tags: lo.logic, gn.general-topology, model-theory, descriptive-set-theory

*This is an attempt at partial progress towards [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453146/quantifier-complexity-of-the-definition-of-continuity-of-functions). Meanwhile, Sam Sanders pointed out that my original term was already in use, as were a couple other back-up terms, so ... oh well.*

For a syntactic class $\Gamma$ and a topological space $\mathcal{X}=(X;\tau)$, say that a function $f:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathcal{X}$ is **$\Gamma$-continuish** iff for every finite tuple of finite-arity continuous functions $\overline{h}:\mathcal{X}^{\overline{a}}\rightarrow\mathcal{X}$ (with $h_i$ having arity $a_i$), every sentence $\varphi$ in $\Gamma$ which is true in the structure $$(X; \overline{h},g)$$ whenever $g:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathcal{X}$ is continuous is also true in the structure $$(X;\overline{h},f).$$

For nice spaces and strong enough $\Gamma$, continuish is just continuous; in particular, in $\mathbb{R}$ (with the usual topology) this happens when $\Gamma$ is $\forall\exists\forall$ (since we can get a pairing operation from the coordinate projections of a space-filling curve). The following question - to which I conjecture a positive answer - is an attempt to provide a "signature-independent" lower bound for the above-linked question:

> **Question**: Over $\mathbb{R}$, is [Conway's base-13 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) $C$ $\forall\exists$-continuish? More generally, are the $\forall\exists$-continuish functions exactly the ones satisfying the intermediate value theorem on all intervals?

It's easy to see that $C$ is not $\exists\forall$-continuish, so a positive answer to this would still leave open the question of whether $\Gamma=\forall\exists\forall$ is optimal. However, it would separate $\mathbb{R}$ and Baire space $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ in terms of "complexity of continuity," since the latter admits a universal continuous function and so in Baire space continuity is equivalent to $\exists\forall$-continuish.

Comment: Is your conjecture/question specifically about the Conway 13 function, or rather, as seems reasonable, about any function whose restriction to any interval is surjective? I gather the idea is that the function exhibits a kind of generic behavior that might allow it to fulfill the $\forall\exists$ properties true of all continuous functions.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Good point; I've tweaked things, but feel free to tweak further.

Comment: The space-filling curve is continuous, yes, but to simulate $\forall x\forall y$ with just one quantifier $\forall r$, what we seem to need is something like an inverse of the space-filling curve. But the continuous space-filling curves are not injective, so what do you have in mind with that?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Each of the coordinate functions of the space-filling curve is continuous. So to say "There are $r,s$ such that $\varphi(r,s)$" we say "there is an $x$ such that $\varphi(p_1(x),p_2(x))$." I've edited to clarify.

Comment: Ah, of course, it simply the composition of the space-filling curve with projection.

Comment: Should this lead to a publication, do make sure to choose your wording carefully: semi-, quasi-, pre-, pseudo-, $\alpha$, $\beta$-, ... continuity are all used in the literature already.

Comment: @SamSanders Dang that's annoying. Thanks for the heads up! I've "fixed" it.

Comment: I think just “$\forall\exists$-continuous” would work, no need for extra prefixes or suffixes.

Comment: Is the noun form "continuishness"? or maybe "continuishity"?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I think it's an irregular adjective; the noun form I had in mind was "continuescence." (Maybe the adjective should be "continuesque"?)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek But where's the fun in that? :P