# Quantifier complexity of definition of compactness

Tags: lo.logic, continuity, nonstandard-analysis

This question is inspired by the post on [quantifier complexity of
continuity](https://mathoverflow.net/q/453146/28128).  We work with metric spaces M
considered as two-sorted first-order structures (M,$\mathbb R$,d,+,⋅,<)
where $d:M^2→\mathbb R$
is the metric, and +,⋅,<
the usual operations and relations on $\mathbb R$.

As is well
known, the classical definition of continuity in $\in$-language
involves two quantifier alternations.  On the other hand, the
st-$\in$-language enables a definition of continuity of lower
quantifier complexity as follows.  Let $\forall^{in},\exists^{in}$ denote
quantification over infinitesimals.  A standard function $f$ is
continuous at a standard point $c$ iff $(\forall^{in} \epsilon)
(\exists^{in} \delta) f(c+\epsilon)=f(c)+\delta$.  This has only one
quantifier alternation.

For compactness, the difference seems to be more far-reaching.  Let's stick with separable metric spaces $(M,d)$ for simplicity (this may not be necessary).  Then $M$ is compact iff $(\forall x\in M) (\exists^{st} y\in M)(\exists^{in}\epsilon\in\mathbb R) d(x,y)=\epsilon$ (in words: "every point is infinitely close to a standard one"), where $\exists^{st}$ denotes quantification over standard elements.  But there is apparently no definition of compactness in the $\in$-language that involves quantification over elements only (the classical definitions involve quantification over sequences or open covers, etc.).  Can this be formally proved?

I should have mentioned also that, if the Heine-Borel theorem is satisfied for an ambient complete space including $M$, then such a definition of compactness does exist since one can formulate both closedness and boundedness while quantifying only over elements (even in this case, one can ask how complex the formula would have to be).  This item requires more precise formalisation in terms of an appropriate structure.

Note. This *question* is formulated in a foundational framework referred to as "nonstandard axiomatic approach" in Joel David Hamkins' useful *answer* [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/226393).  Such an approach is the only one that enables a study of the role of the axiom of choice in infinitesimal analysis in the spirit (though not the letter) of reverse mathematics, as outlined in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/448927) to the same question.  This approach suggests that the real numbers possess resources undreamt of by Dedekind, which is usually a source of celebration in mathematics.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, the metric is a function but the definition does not quantify over functions.  Quantification over reals seems to be within the bounds of a philosophy of looking for definitions that quantify only over "elements".  Otherwise I am certainly flexible; any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek,what I tentatively proposed is a definition that involves quantification over elements only, which as you pointed out should include elements of both $M$ and $\mathbb R$.  I don't know if this is a sensible question or not; I would appreciate hearing in either case.

Comment: Any equalities or inequalities, as in the definition of continuity.  It might be obvious that there is no such definition (for compactness) in the $\in$-language; I don't have enough experience to see this immediately.  Should I allow more in order to get a sensible question?  I only mentioned "philosophy" because some modifications may be needed to make this into a sensible question.  @Emil

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, I clarified the Heine-Borel remark.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, the point about $\in$-language is that formulas only use the language limited to the membership relation, as in $x\in M$.  Relative to the st-$\in$-language, one can also use quantifiers decorated by "in" or "st", as in the well-known internal set theories (which have been around for half a century).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, I allow $\forall x\in M$ in the formulas.  For example, the definition of continuity only uses quantification over elements, and it certainly contains several "$\in$" symbols.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, Fine.  I am just using "$\in$-language" and "st-$\in$-language" to contrast traditional set-theoretic definitions, on the one hand, and those that allow the standardness predicate, on the other.  This happens to be Karel Hrbacek's terminology.  We published several papers using it, in leading logic journals, and the referees did not object.  See https://u.math.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/infinitesimals.html

Comment: That sounds good, thanks.  @Emil

Comment: I cleaned up my comments in this thread as the question now includes a workable definition. However, I note that the Heine–Borel stuff still does not fit with the rest, as it requires a rather different setup with quantification over elements of a (fixed?) ambient space, presumably referring to $M$ as a unary predicate.

Comment: I think you can show that already for uniformly discrete metric spaces finiteness (and therefore compactness) cannot be expressed in first-order logic.

Comment: Readers are advised to attend to the implicit idiosyncratic foundational framework of the question. Namely, the OP says that a separable metric space "$M$ is compact iff $(\forall x\in M)(\exists^{st}y\in M)(\exists^{in}\epsilon) d(x,y)=\epsilon$." But this only works in that idiosyncratic foundation. Most mathematicians, for example, would say that the standard real field (the one with only standard numbers) is a separable metric space but not compact, yet every real number has distance $0$ to itself. In the internal set theory framework, this standard version of $\mathbb{R}$ does not exist.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins That is a little bit of a misrepresentation:  Nelson, upon introducing his internal set theory, clearly states that "the real number field is still the same: it just has more structure, provided by 'st(x)'. "

Comment: Moreover, the work of van den Berg et al (APAL2012) allows one to show that nonstandard definitions correspond to 'constructive' definitions (not involving NSA) via a syntactical translation.  For instance, nonstandard continuity translates to 'epsilon-delta continuity with a modulus'.

Comment: Right, I agree with all that (except that my remarks are not misrepresentation). The point is that one must understand the OP in light of this idiosyncratic foundational stance. In particular, the compactness characterization does not apply to the space $M$ consisting of the standard real numbers only, which is a space that many mathematicians will expect to exist, but which does not in this framework.

Comment: To be honest, this is the kind of red herring I have always been annoyed by: people have done studies comparing "teaching usual calculus vs teaching calculus using Keisler's book"; the latter worked better (see google).  Steffen Lempp (recursion theorist) reported the same when teaching from Keisler's book. This advantage of NSA is at least in part due to e.g. open cover compactness having a simpler definition: beginning students just do not get the former (though sequential compactness is a reasonably substitute).

Comment: If I recall, Keisler's book distinguishes clearly between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^*$ and states the transfer property very clearly. I find that an extremely clear, welcome approach to NSA. That is the approach that I always take. What I find unhelpful (and many people find it confusing or even incoherent) is when people say "for every natural number" but they are including the nonstandard numbers. Similarly as in this question. An unnecessary conflation of $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{R}^*$.

Comment: If we could define "compact" in the language you've described, then we could also define "compact, nonempty, and has no isolated points" (since the latter two properties are easy to describe in this language). But then the downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem would give us a countable metric space with these propoerties. This is a contradiction, because every compact, nonempty metric space with no isolated points has size $\mathfrak{c}$. (I'm not sure I understand your question, which is why I'm making this a comment and not an answer. Does this answer your question?)

Comment: @WillBrian I almost posted an answer with much the same argument. The catch is that the countable elementary submodel from Löwenheim–Skolem will not preserve $\mathbb R$ as the second sort of the structure, but also replace it with a countable subset, hence it will no longer be the correct structure associated with the countable metric space. It may well happen that there is no proper elementary submodel that contains all of $\mathbb R$: e.g., if the space you start with is $M=[0,1]$, you can define a bijection between $M$ and the subset $[0,1]$ of the $\mathbb R$ sort in the structure.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Good point. What if we go the other direction and use the upward L-S theorem to get a compact metric space of size $>\mathfrak{c}$? This is also impossible -- every compact metric space has size $\leq\!\aleph_0$ or $\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: @WillBrian Well that’s the same problem (even worse): the new structure may have a proper extension of $\mathbb R$ as the codomain of the metric.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Ha, good point. OK, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @JamesHanson, that sounds interesting. Would you like to provide some details and formulate this as an answer?

Answer (score 8):

Often the way you prove that something isn't formalizable in first-order logic is (ironically enough) with a compactness proof. This is how you show, for instance, that there isn't a first-order theory in the language of equality whose class of models is precisely the finite sets.

For your question though, you have this extra stipulation that the structure has $\mathbb{R}$ as a second sort that is always the standard $\mathbb{R}$. This makes applying compactness arguments directly difficult, since they can't guarantee that the example produced will have the reals sort be the standard $\mathbb{R}$. (That said, a related question is whether compactness is formalizable in continuous logic and it turns out there that the answer is also no precisely by this kind of compactness argument.)

However, there's a second tool that is relevant here, which is [Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_game). In some sense Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé games are just a particular semantic way of talking about formulas, but they're often in practice a little bit easier to think about.

---

Let $D$ be the class of structures in your language with standard $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying that for any $x,y \in M$, $d(x,y) \in \{0,1\}$. Clearly a metric space in $D$ is compact if and only if its $M$-sort is finite. Furthermore, a structure in $D$ is determined up to isomorphism by the cardinality of its $M$ sort. For each cardinal $\kappa$, let $\Delta_\kappa$ be some fixed structure in $D$ satisfying $|M^{\Delta_\kappa}| =\kappa$.

> **Proposition.** For sentence $\varphi$, there is a finite $n$ such that for any cardinals $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ with $\kappa,\lambda > n$, $\Delta_\kappa\models \varphi$ if and only if $\Delta_\lambda\models \varphi$.

*Proof.* By standard facts about Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé games, it is enough to show that for any $m$ (corresponding roughly to the quantifier complexity of $\varphi$), there is an $n$ such that for any $\kappa,\lambda > n$, duplicator has a winning strategy in the Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé game on $\Delta_\kappa$ and $\Delta_\lambda$ of length $m$, but this is fairly immediate. We can actually just let $n$ be $m$. Duplicator's winning strategy is this: If spoiler chooses an element of $\mathbb{R}$, duplicator chooses the same element of $\mathbb{R}$. If spoiler chooses an element of $M$ that has not been chosen before, duplicator chooses some element of $M$ (in the other structure) that has also not been chosen before. Since $\kappa, \lambda > n$, this will always be possible. Finally, if spoiler chooses an element of $M$ that has been chosen before (which really spoiler shouldn't be doing anyway since it can't possibly help to win), then duplicator picks the element of the other structure chosen the last time spoiler played that element. It's straightforward to check that plays resulting from this strategy are always wins for duplicator. $\square$

> **Corollary.** There is no sentence $\varphi$ such that $X \models \varphi$ if and only if $M^X$ is compact.

*Proof.* If there were such a sentence, then we'd have that for any $\kappa$, $\Delta_\kappa \models \varphi$ if and only if $M^{\Delta_\kappa}$ is finite, but this contradicts the proposition. $\square$

Comment: Did you ever get around to publishing this?

Comment: @MikhailKatz I wasn't planning on publishing this.