# Comparison of model-theoretic and axiomatic approaches to NSA

Tags: nonstandard-analysis

This question is motivated by the discussion in the comments to [this
post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/454016/28128).  The question concerns
a comparison of model-theoretic (extension) approaches to nonstandard
analysis, and axiomatic (syntactic) approaches such as
[IST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_set_theory), BST, HST,
and others.

Consider the following two examples.

1. An internal subset of $\mathbb R^\ast$ which is already contained
   in $\mathbb R\subseteq \mathbb R^\ast$ is necessarily finite.  The
   proof of this as found in a popular textbook such as
   [Goldblatt's](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=4118501315415182310)
   is somewhat involved.  Meanwhile, in axiomatic set theories, the fact
   that an infinite set must contain nonstandard elements is immediate
   from Idealisation.
2. Overspill: every internal subset of $\mathbb N^\ast$ containing
   $\mathbb N$ must also contain a nonstandard integer, or equivalently an internal
   set containing all nonstandard integers must contain a standard
   integer.  Proofs in the model-theoretic approach need to develop
   *internal induction* or *internal well-ordering* first, whereas in the
   axiomatic approach one just applies the usual well-ordering property of $\mathbb N$ to
   derive a contradiction from the existence of a set of all nonstandard
   integers.
3. Another example that occurred to me while I was preparing a recent talk is the integral.  In model-theoretic approaches, one defines it as the shadow (i.e., standard part) of a suitable hyperfinite sum.  To justify such a procedure, one needs to verify that hyperfinite sums indeed exist and behave as finite sums in a suitable sense.  In the axiomatic approaches, the integral is the shadow of a *finite* sum as the index runs from 1 to $\mu$ (where $\mu$ is a nonstandard integer in $\mathbb N$), and no additional verifications are necessary.

I am looking for further examples of this type so as to illustrate the
fact that sometimes axiomatic approaches have their advantages
over the model-theoretic ones (and vice versa).  The kind of examples
I am looking for would preferably be applicable also to the weaker
systems SPOT or SCOT.  Note that, even though the axioms of SPOT do
not include idealisation, one can actually prove countable
Idealisation within SPOT.

Note. To answer some of the queries in the *comments*, the standard reference for axiomatic nonstandard analysis is [Kanovei and Reeken](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-08998-9) where theories IST, BST, HST are presented in detail.  The more recent theories SPOT and SCOT are outlined [here](https://u.math.biu.ac.il/%7Ekatzmik/spot.html) with the appropriate links.  Consistency: all of these theories are equiconsistent with ZF(C).  Conservativity: all of these theories are conservative over ZFC.  SPOT is conservative over ZF.  SCOT is conservative over ZF+ADC.  Interpretability: (not IST but) BST admits a standard core interpretation in ZFC (every model of ZFC is the "standard core" of a suitable model of BST).  Multiverse: the Gitman-Hamkins "toy model" of the  multiverse is compatible with BST in the sense that two adjacent universes have the property that the smaller one is the standard core of the larger one, as discussed [here](https://u.math.biu.ac.il/%7Ekatzmik/infinitesimals.html#17f).

Comment: What are BST, HST, SPOT, and SCOT?

Comment: How do you justify taking an axiomatic approach without first knowing that (under mild assumptions) the relevant theory is consistent? To me it seems that the examples of "axiomatic efficiency" in this question are just hiding the (usually model-theoretic) work elsewhere.

Comment: BST, HST, SPOT, and SCOT are nonstandard set theories extending ZFC/ZF in different (but equi-consistent) ways

Comment: Noah Schweber: *hiding* is not an appropriate word here. Once a benchmark thm is established, no reference to it in proofs of different theorems can be considered as *hiding* anything.

Comment: @NoahSchweber How does model theory offer reassurance in this area without falling back on axioms? (the models one constructs exist within another axiomatic system)

Comment: I would find it important to inquire to what extent the nonstandard theories are mutually interpretable or bi-interpretable with the corresponding standard theories. It seems that ZFC is likely bi-interpretable with a suitable nonstandard theory, simply by interpreting via suitable iterated ultrapowers of V. If the theories are bi-interpretable, then they are arguably semantically equivalent variations of same underlying subject. It would be fruitless to argue for one over the other in this case except on style or convenience. So what is the interpretability status of these theories?

Comment: @AlecRhea That's the source of my "under mild assumptions." Of course a model-theoretic argument only yields conditional results (but the same is true for anything else, really), but even conditional results are useful for establishing confidence. For instance, speaking only for myself I find that I have a much higher degree of confidence in (say) the consistency of BST *after* seeing a proof of consistency relative to ZFC.

Comment: @VladimirKanovei "Once a benchmark thm is established, no reference to it in proofs of different theorems can be considered as hiding anything" But there *is* no reference to such a benchmark in the arguments in the OP that I see.

Comment: @VladimirKanovei Where are good references for these theories? Google is failing me.

Comment: @Noah: ""How do you justify taking an axiomatic approach without first knowing that (under mild assumptions) the relevant theory is consistent? To me it seems that the examples of 'axiomatic efficiency' in this question are just hiding the (usually model-theoretic) work elsewhere."

This is a good objection, but notice that it only makes sense if you postulate that the appropriate starting point is an \in-theory, rather than a st-\in theory.  The point I would like to make is that ...

Comment: ...  the standardness predicate is not some kind of exotic post-modern innovation that must necessarily be viewed as superstructure to the "normal" set theory.   My evidence for this is that the assignable/inassignable distinction was already in Leibniz, so it is arguably natural enough to be included as part of the axiomatic background.  In other words, once the conservativity of the st-\in-theories are justified by what Schweber refers to as "model-theoretic work", it becomes clear that the st-\in-language is as legitimate as the \in-language rather than being some kind of stepchild.

Comment: I should mention also that adopting Hamkins' "well-foundedness mirage" axiom is  helpful in understanding the spririt of axiomatic NSA.

Comment: In items 1 and 2, I wonder whether you are exaggerating the difficulty in using the model theoretic approach. For 1, if $A$ is infinite, including a sequence $\langle a_n\rangle_n$ of distinct elements, and then consider $a^*_N$ for some nonstandard $N$. By assumption this is standard, and so by elementarity it must have a standard index in the sequence, but it doesn't. Contradiction. For 2, overspill is immediate from induction, which is part of the theory we work in. You make it sound like a complicated development?

Comment: Your argument for (1) only works for standard sets, not for internal sets.  If you pick a sequence of elements of an internal set, there is no guarantee that $a_N$ will be in the set if it is only known to be internal.  Consider for example $S=\{1,2,3,\ldots, K\}$; if $H>K$ your argument fails.  A further objection is that choosing a sequence involves choice, whereas axiomatic approaches can do without choice at all. @Joel

Comment: As far as your objection to item (2) is concerned, I am not sure what you mean.  It is true that it boils down to induction, but only *internal* induction, as I mentioned in my *question*.  In axiomatic frameworks, this is the same old induction (of course modulo the "idiosyncratic, unhelpful, confusing, and incoherent" aspects you mentioned in an earlier *comment* of yours).  @Joel

Comment: Incidentally, user Rivers seems to share your concerns; see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4770885/confusion-about-the-model-in-robert-s-nonstandard-analysis#comment10135719_4770885  @JoelDavidHamkins

Comment: Ah, sorry, indeed I was thinking of standard sets. I don't know anything really about internal sets, as I rarely work in that framework.

Comment: By the standard easy yoga with the ultrafilter, a standard set is finite if and only if its natural extension is finite, so one wouldn't need choice here. @JoelDavidHamkins

Comment: @ James Hanson Regarding HST and BST see DOI 10.1070/RM2007v062n01ABEH004381 , for sPOT and SCOT see DOI 10.1016/j.apal.2021.102959 and sorry for such a delay

Comment: @James, see comment above.